# Setting up Django static with Docker/Nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am Dockerizing my Django/React app but having issues getting the static files to show up on the prod server.

*Project Directory*:

```
.
├── README.md
├── backend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Dockerfile.prod
│   ├── backend
│   ├── entrypoint.prod.sh
│   ├── entrypoint.sh
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── static
├── docker-compose.ci.yml
├── docker-compose.prod.yml
├── docker-compose.yml
├── frontend
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Dockerfile.prod
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── build
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── src
│   └── webpack.config.js
└── nginx
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── nginx.conf
```

*nginx.conf*

```
upstream backend {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root "/var/www/frontend";
    }    

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
    
    location /static/ {
        alias /backend/static;
    }
}
```

*Django static setting*:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

*docker-compose.ci.yml* (builds the images):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: "${BACKEND_IMAGE}"
    command: gunicorn backend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/backend/static
      - media_volume:/backend/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file: .env
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: "${FRONTEND_IMAGE}"
    volumes:
      - frontend_build:/frontend/build
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/backend/static
      - frontend_build:/var/www/frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend

volumes:
  frontend_build:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

In the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools it shows this URL when trying to load static:

> Request URL: http://ipaddress/static/admin/css/nav_sidebar.cs

Comment: What does `STATIC_ROOT` resolve to? It should be `/backend/static/`.

Comment: Yes, it resolves to `/backend/static/`

Comment: Some sanity checks. Did you run `collectstatic`? Do you see your static files in the `nginx` container `docker-compose exec nginx ls /backend/static`?

Comment: `collectstatic` is run during the build - it's not an issue that I am copying the files over, right? When logging into the server I can run `docker exec -it b43 sh` and `ls /backend` to see the `/static` dir.

Comment: By "during the build" do you mean `collectstatic` in your Dockerfile?

Comment: `collectstatic` is ran during the `build` workflow in github actions as part of my CI/CD pipeline. During the `build` stage the images are saved to github packages and then after the PR is merged into the master branch, the images are puled onto the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240370/discussion-between-konstantin-k-and-david-alford).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static files collected inside the `backend` container during the build are hidden by `static_volume` which is mounted when you run `docker-compose`.

When you mount a volume on top of a directory, you only see the contents of the volume, not the files that were in the directory before.

To fix this you could

- Run `collectstatic` after the volume is mounted. I.e. after the server is up
- Copy static files produced by Django into the `nginx` container at build time (no need to use the volume anymore)